# gnuplot/tk: how to use tkcanvas support gnuplot command like set style fill set xtics rotate

Tags: command, gnuplot, histogram

Now I installed the gnuplot version 4.6 and want to draw some histogram chart using the `tkcanvas` terminal, but find some commands don't work:

1. `set style fill solid 1.0`

   But the bar is still empty inside
2. `title`

   Maybe it is related to the first issue. but in the legend part, beside the title text no bar placed beside to show which color it denotes.
3. `set xtics rotate by -45`

   The labels along x axis has no rotation

Here is a short example:

```
set term tk
set style data histograms
set style histogram clustered
set style fill solid 1.0 border lt -1
set xtics rotate by -45
plot for [col=2:5] "histogramdata.txt" using col:xticlabels(1) title columnheader(col)
```

OK, based on my study I find what the issue. yes, when use tkcanvas as the terminal, the set style fill solid and set xtics rotate both failed. Them can work well for x11 terminals

so the name for this post should be tkcanvas cann't support gnuplot command like: set style fill....

Any idea?

Comment: forget to post my code. Sorry for that.

Comment: I've never worked with the `tkcanvas` terminal, can't help you here.

Comment: yes,currently the default terminal is unknown for gnuplot. I checked X11,but not install yet. so directly use tk to contain what is produced by gnuplot.

Comment: Ok, based on my study. I find a workaround. Use gif terminal in gnuplot to generate a gif file,which supports fill solid setting for bar charting. And then use tk image command to read in the gif file, which is also supported by default tk package.

Comment: You should consider using the `pngcairo` terminal which generates higher-quality images than the `gif` terminal.

Comment: Yes png is better. But based on my test, tk image can not read in png format file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing nothing wrong, the `tkcanvas` terminal simply doesn't support filled polygons and rotated text, as the `test` command also tells you:

To see this, use the simple script

```
set terminal tkcanvas
set output 'test.file'
test
```

And then, after invoking `wish`, execute the following Tcl/Tk commands:

```
source test.file
canvas .c
pack .c
gnuplot .c
```

which on my system gives

[image: Output of the <code>test</code> command with the <code>tkcanvas</code> terminal]

Comment: I have an idea. Use gnuplot save the plot as a image. And use tcl/tk to read the image and show it in canvas. Can this workaround work well. I will test it later. Any reference,thanks ahead?